# cypress-cucumber - Passing value from one step defination to another step defination

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using cypress-cucumber. I have below scenario

```
When I go to home page I extract the price
When I go to shopping cart page I extract the price
Then the price on the home page and shopping cart page is same
```

Step definitions:

```
When('I go to home page I extract the price', () => {
    ......
    ......
    const homePagePrice = 100
)
})
```

```
When('I go to shopping cart page I extract the price', () => {
    ......
    ......
    const shoppingCartPagePrice = 100
)
})
```

```
Then('the price on the home page and shopping cart page is same', () => {
    ......
    ......
)
})
```

My question is: How do I pass the price extracted in home page and in shopping cart page on the step definition for "Then the price on the home page and shopping cart page is same"

What is the best way / best practice to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the example at [Sharing context](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#sharing-context), although I think there's a typo in there

```js
Given('I go to the add new item page', () => {
  cy.visit('/addItem');
});

When('I add a new item', () => {
  cy.get('input[name="addNewItem"]').as('addNewItemInput');  // grab the value
  cy.get('@addNewItemInput').type('My item');
  cy.get('button[name="submitItem"]').click();
})

Then('I see new item added', () => {
  cy.get('td:contains("My item")');
});

Then('I can add another item', () => {
  cy.get('@addNewItemInput').should('be.empty');             // use the value
});
```

---

Your code...

```js
When('I go to home page I extract the price', () => {
  const homePagePrice = 100
  cy.wrap(homePagePrice).as('homePagePrice');
})

When('I go to shopping cart page I extract the price', () => {
  const shoppingCartPagePrice = 100
  cy.wrap(shoppingCartPagePrice).as('shoppingCartPagePrice');
})

Then('the price on the home page and shopping cart page is same', () => {
  cy.get('@homePagePrice').then(homePagePrice => {
    cy.get('@shoppingCartPagePrice').then(shoppingCartPagePrice => {
      expect(homePagePrice).to.eq(shoppingCartPagePrice)
    })
  })
})
```